# pspicture-eps picture

Tags: pdftex, miktex, eps, pspicture

I am having problems to compile eps picture and pspicture to Pdf simultaneously. I am using Miktex 2.9-winedit32. I tried Latex-dvips-pspdf  and it gives me an error. I would like to know if there is a easy way to do so? Thank you for your attention

Comment: Which error? Please read http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pstricks` graphics can be compiled directly with `pdflatex`. You just have to load the `auto-pst-pdf` package *after* pstricks, and add the `--enable-write18` switch to `pdflatex` from the `Execution modes` interface in  WinEdt.

As for the `.eps` files, you can convert them to `.pdf` format  with a tight bounding box with the excellent tool [epspdf-setup](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/epspdf-setup/), available from CTAN.